# What is regex to to fail when string has pipe and colon characters without escaping?

Tags: java, regex

Requirement is build a Java regex to allow all characters excluding pipe and colon when not preceded by escape

```
|------|-----------------|
|Input | Expected output |
|------|-----------------|
|aaaaa |      pass       |
|------|-----------------|
|aaa:  |      fail       |
|------|-----------------|
|aaa|  |      fail       |
|------|-----------------|
|aaa:  |      pass       |
|------|-----------------|
|:     |      fail       |
|------|-----------------|
|\:    |      pass       |
|------|-----------------|
|\\:   |      fail       |
|------|-----------------|
|\\\:  |      pass       |
|------|-----------------|
|\\\\  |      pass       |
|------|-----------------|


Tried following just for colon use-case - "(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\:"
```

Where behavior is

- correctly fails on ':' and colon preceded by even number of back
  slash
- correctly passes on colon preceded by odd number of back slash
- Incorrectly passes on "aaa:aaa"

Comment: Why is the 4th one (`aaa:`) a pass, when the second one (also `aaa:`) is a fail?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this atomic group based regex:

```
^(?>[^:|\\]|\\.)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tj3QnJ/5)

For Java use:

```
final String regex = "^(?>[^:|\\\\\]|\\\\.)+$";
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?>`: Start atomic group

  - `[^:|\\]`: Match any character that is not `|` and `:` and `\`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\\`: Match a `\`
  - `.`: Match next character after a `\`
- `)+`: End atomic group. Match one or more of this group till end.
- `$`: End

It is recommended to use [*atomic group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to **avoid backtracking** to improve regex performance.

Comment: Thanks! Works except for cases if preceded by more than one backslash. In case if preceded by 2(even) backslashes, tests should fail while for 3 (add) backslashes tests should pass.

Comment: Yes, I meant look behind. We are expecting a serialized string where [:|] are reserved. If case, :| are used, they should be escaped.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks you for the updated regex! I believe all cases are passing except "\\\\".

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you so much!!